# python move files from newline to previous line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let say i have the text file "test.txt". It contains the following:

```
1line

2line

3line
4line

5line6line
```

is there way to make the output :

```
1line2line3line4line5line6line
```

or if the newlines are even like

```
line1
line2
line3
```

to : `line1line2line3`

Comment: read all text to memory, remove all `'\n'` and save all text back to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strip()`

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r')
out = open('output.txt', 'w+')
for line in inp.readlines():
    out.write(line.strip())
inp.close()
out.close()
```

[strip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Since all it seems like you're doing is really removing newlines, I would do something like this, personally:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as file1:
    with open('output.txt','w') as file2:
        file2.write(file1.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

Using the with keyword ensures your files close properly, and this has the advantage of not using any iterators.